# Saving media streams based on size and time criteria in a direct show filter

Tags: directshow, mp4

I just have simple filter graph whick takes media streams from rtsp source[ generally h264 and mp4 ] and save them using  an mp4 muxer to a file...

```
RtspSourceFilter ---> MP4 Muxer ---> File Writer.
```

It works OK. But i have constraint[ new requirment now]. I have to write file based on two criteria: their size and duration...Suppose that user can define rules such as:

```
if duration > 1 hour or size > 1 gb then write stream to new file
```

In my graph in order to this,

> I have to stop my graph  based on conditions and create and start new
>   one with new file name...

That is bad since at ever file  i have to re-connect my source and possibly lost some data...

What is the best way to deal with it ?

**My Solution: [ But not satisfied with it ]**

I have the source code of RtspSourceFilter and MP4Muxer[open source] so that forgot FileWriter...MP4 Muxer became a writer with Muxer...So stop it internally and write when necessary and then cretae new file...Do some buffering for not looosing data...

```
   RTSP Source Filter ---> New MP4 Writer [ a writer with mp4 muxer in it]
```

But this introduce unnecessary complexity...Now i became maintainer of MUX operation via New MP4 Writer...Since i have no time to really understand what Mux do, i have to modify-hack it to behave what i want... Analogy: I have car and i will make a helicopter from it...It will be very ugly and un-trusted helicopter...Probably my New MP4 Filter [code] will be so...[ Big Ball of Mud]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [GMFBridge](http://www.gdcl.co.uk) may be of use to you. It allows you to create one source graph, and multiple sink graphs. Then when your constraint is met, bridge the source graph to a new sink graph.

If you put the bridge in buffer (non-discard) mode, you should not loose any samples.

However, you will have to investigate if this solution works for you. Have a look at the sample applications for a quick overview.

Comment: I used it...Not works well..Problem with video data...And i have to stop first part of graph in GMFBridge which means i have to reconnect my source...